Не задается высота дочернему блоку в относительных единицах
Не задается высота дочернему блоку section в относительных единицах, когда пытаюсь заполнить на всю высоту родителя. Если задавать высоту, например, в пикселях то все работает. Подключенных скриптов нет. Кэш чистил. В чем может быть причина? Сломал уже голову. Помогите!!!
<body>
   <header style="min-height: 100px"></header>
   <main style="min-height: calc(100vh - 200px)">

      <section style="height: 100%"></section>  <!-- так не срабатывает-->
      <section style="height: 100px"></section>  <!-- так срабатывает -->

   </main>
   <footer style="min-height: 100px"></footer>
</body>


Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
